# Where to put the "now" in?

Tags: grammar

I am not sure how to use the "now", where to put it in the sentence.

I have:

> "I studied [...] in the joint masters program [...] and I want to
>   continue my career [...]".

I think for understanding it is good to emphasize that I graduated and NOW I want to continue my career in [....]. That's why I think a now would be good.

What is correct?

> "I studied [...] in the joint masters program [...] and I now want to
>   continue my career [...]"

or

> "I studied [...] in the joint masters program [...] and now I want to
>   continue my career [...]"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are correct, as the sentences have the same overall.

However

> "I studied [...] in the joint masters program [...] and I now want to continue my career [...]"

May possibly indicate that you have only now decided to continue your career in B after completing A,

whereas

> "I studied [...] in the joint masters program [...] and now I want to continue my career [...]"

May indicate that this was always your intention. You did A, and had planned to do once you had completed B.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with your assessment of the differences. I think there is little if any distinction between the two options except perhaps the tone, with *I now want* striking a slightly more formal tone.

Comment: True. Thus why I began with "May possibly indicate", as most people will find them identical. The only people who may find difference are pedants such as ourselves.